# tensorflow map function to mulitple tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the following function in a custom layer in TensorFlow to rearrange query, key values:

```
q, k, v = map(lambda t: rearrange(t, 'b n (h d) -> b h n d', h = self.heads), (q, k, v))
```

and it throws this warning:

`WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/pyct/static_analysis/liveness.py:83: Analyzer.lamba_check (from tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct.static_analysis.liveness) is deprecated and will be removed after 2023-09-23. Instructions for updating: Lambda fuctions will be no more assumed to be used in the statement where they are used, or at least in the same block. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56089`

Is there a more TensorFlowic way of doing this?

I tried using map_fn as follows and it throws the the same warning and an error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from einops import rearrange
a = tf.random.uniform((1, 196, 196))
b, c, d = tf.map_fn(lambda t: rearrange(t, 'b (h n) d -> b h n d', h=14), [a, a, a])
```

From documentation, it seems `tf.map_fn` but it seems to work on a stack of tensors. Will it be better to stack the tensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of mistakes-
First you need to use the `einops tensorflow layer` for `rearrange`. The below changes should work:

```
from einops.layers.tensorflow import Rearrange

a = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 196, 196))
q, k, v = tf.map_fn(fn= Rearrange('b (h n) d -> b h n d', h=14), elems=tf.stack([a, a, a]))
print(q.shape, k.shape, v.shape)
# (1, 14, 14, 196) (1, 14, 14, 196) (1, 14, 14, 196)
```

Comment: Still throws the same warning.

Comment: Made the edits to fix the warnings.

Comment: Thank you. It works. This seems great. Do you think normal functions which are not class like `Rearrange` partial functions would be a great idea instead of lambda?